# Bluetooth Permissions not working with accompanist-permissions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to request Bluetooth permissions for my app following [this](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/permissions/RequestMultiplePermissionsSample.kt) example.

If I run the above example, it works correctly.

However if I update the permissions to instead be:

```kotlin
    val multiplePermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    )
```

Nothing happens when I click on the `Request permissions` button. I've already confirmed that my `AndroidManifest` contains

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Did I miss some step? Is there something special about requesting Bluetooth permissions vs others?

Comment: Both `permission.BLUETOOTH` and `permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` have protection level `normal`. Such permissions shouldn't be requested at runtime, you just need to declare your use of them in your manifest. Note however that there are [newer bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions) that you may need to declare **and** request at runtime depending on your `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: That's good to know about Bluetooth. I've modified my code to use [this](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/permissions/RequestPermissionSample.kt) example for requesting location permissions and I'm still hitting the same problem though when I click the button.